# what could happen if data is not transferred in sliding window protocol?

Tags: networking, tcp, buffer, flow-control

[image]
source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29

is it like blocking condition,when the reciver recieves only half of the 
window size of data bytes from the sender?(sender expecting an ack after sending window size!!!).the think he is mentioned that no other entity tries to communicate,what that mean?.why because after half of the window size, receiver still expects remaining and what could happen if sender is in mute?.what receiver does?,is still waiting?,what the sender expects in this situation?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is possibly more appropriate on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BigHomie could you explain this?